# React Native Base disabling button doesn't change color

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm using the React Native Base [Button](https://docs.nativebase.io/button) component.

When I pass it the `disabled` prop, it successfully disables it, but (unlike in the documentation) the color doesn't change at all to indicate the disabled state. Any idea if I need to do something else or am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `disabled` prop does disable the button, but if you look closely at the documentation it's using a *different* prop, `isDisabled`. That prop disables it and affects the color.

```
<Button isDisabled> Press Me </Button>
```